# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to K when using conditional operator

Tags: java, generics, conditional-operator

I have the following code,

```
class Foo<K> {

    public <T> T createK() {
        return null;
    }

    public void foo() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        K k = (1==1)?null:createK();
    }
}
```

However, it didn't compile. It caused the following compilation error (Oracle Java 7) on the line with the conditional operator:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to K

When I rewrite the `foo()` method as follows,

```
public void foo() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    K k = null;
    if (1==1)
        k = null;
    else
        k = createK();
}
```

Then it compiles fine. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the conditional operator is not exactly same as `if-else` conditional, but this is a different issue.

[**This is a known bug**](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6721089) with type inference of generic type parameter with conditional operator which doesn't work as expected.

The solution is to provide explicit type argument:

```
K k1 = (1==1) ? null : this.<K>createK();
```

...this would work, however with compiler warning - *Dead Code* (of course, due to `1 == 1` part). Note, how we need to explicit use `this` to invoke the method with explicit type argument. Simply doing `<K>createK()` won't work.

Adding the explicit type argument with method invocation - `this.<K>createK();` forces the type `T` to be inferred as `K`, which is otherwise inferred as `Object`.

---

However, I suspect that your doubt is really related to the type inference. It's just a coincidence that the issue came out to be that. Even though, to get some idea about how conditional operators work in different situations, and what the type of its result is, you can schedule a visit to [JLS §15.25 - Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

Comment: Thanks, quite frankly I got some humorous yet mildly sarcastic comments for no particular reason other than perhaps not being able to express in a 80-character title the exact nuance of non-equivalence that puzzled me. If anybody can suggest a more appropriate concise title for my question I will gladly change it.

Comment: Marcus, I sanitized the whole question. I guess you was being a bit too subjective/argumentative ;)

Comment: By the way ... *Dead Code* is caused by `(1==1)`. Also, the actual `createK()` doesn't take any arguments. This is further completely unrelated to the concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC. Yeah. Should have added that. :)

Comment: @BalusC many thanks for editing; `(1==1)` was just to make the example as short as possible (e.g. avoid declaring and initializing a boolean in a separate line).

Answer (score 4):

No, the *ternary* (i.e. the `? :`) is a *very* different beast from `if ... then ... else`.

The ternary is an *operator* and the two alternatives have to be ***expressions evaluating to the same type***.

`if ... then ... else` is a convenient programming construct; the bits in between are *statements* not expressions.

In fact, the *entire* ternary construct is an expression, whereas the `if ... then ... else` is itself a statement. (You can assign a value to a ternary; e.g. `foo = ... ? ... : ...` but `foo = if ... then ... else` is meaningless and therefore syntatically invalid.)

Comment: +1, and in fact, `if...else` is itself a statement, while the ternary is an expression.

Comment: Sure, but in the example above the bits in between are indeed expressions, so I guess it boils down to their not being the same type

Comment: Might I recommend you take a look at the *grammar* pages of Kernighan and Ritchie the C Programming Language? It applies well to Java and you'll appreciate the difference in a way that a description here can't approach.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus They're what the JLS calls "[expression statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)" -- expressions that can be used as statements. In the context of an if-then-else's blocks, the relevant attribute is their statement-ness, not their expression-ness.

Comment: @Bathsheba Though there is major difference in how `if-else` and conditional operator work, still the issue is something else here. It's related to generic type inference. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19305223/1679863).

Comment: @Rohit Jain; you are correct - about to award +1 - I paid too much attention to the question title. I like my rant on grammar so I'll leave this answer in and untouched.

Comment: You're both right and deserve a +1. ;) There's an issue with the generic type inference on the part of the JLS authors, and an issue with not understanding that "the conditional ?: operator is NOT equivalent to an if-then-else" on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile because the types of both sides of a conditional *expression* must match. There is no such requirement for the `if` *statement* - in fact, there is no requirement for the two parts to be related to each other in any way, let alone assigning the same variable.

Adding a cast fixes your conditional ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/lFsJx0)):

```
K k = (1==1)?null:(K)createK();
```

Answer (score 1):

Those operators are different.

1) In case of `if ... then ... else` there is no limitations of actions

2) Ternary operator. Using that both sides must have the same type.

You can fix everything with cast:

```
K k = (1 == 1) ? null : (K)(createK());
```

Answer (score -1):

Using condition ? valueA : valueB operator is meaningful only if there is an Lvalue,

Lvalue = condition ? valueA : valueB

The exact meannig of this operator can be transformed to an if else statement:

```
int y,z;
```

int     x= (y==0) ? y+1 : z+3

this ends up to be the same as:

```
if(y==0)
{
    x=y+1;
}else
{
    x = z+3;
}
```